# Dimmed LEDs flickering: is it the bulbs' or the dimmer's fault?

Tags: lighting, led, dimmer-switch, light-bulb

I have this dimmer https://www.amazon.es/iolloi-interruptor-regulador-encendido-incandescente/dp/B0894KNN65 feeding two of these lightbulbs: https://www.efectoled.com/es/comprar-bombillas-led-e27-filamento/1096-bombilla-led-e27-regulable-filamento-planet-g95-6w-8445044014651.html?

They work pretty well and i can dim them to an incredibly low intensity. Everything is brand new.

At first I wasn't noticing any flickering at all but now I'm starting to notice a very slight flickering. By "flickering" i mean random slight fluctuations in brightness, kind of like those of a candle, but obviously way more subtle.
It happens from time to time when I keep them at low intensity.

The lightbulbs are supposed to be dimmable and the dimmer is supposed to be suitable for LED and the minimum load is supposed to be 3W.

How can I know whether the lightbulbs or the dimmer are to blame? Or is a small level of flickering just to be expected?

Comment: Try different lamps in the dimmer sockets or try the bulbs that flicker on another dimmer. It can even be 1 flaky lamp causing all the problems.

Comment: Have you tried to replace the flickering light bulb?

Comment: Thanks guys, I already figured that trying the same bulbs on a different dimmer and the same dimmer on different bulbs would allow me to narrow down the culprit, but I don't have other dimmers or bulbs at hand and I don't want to buy them just for testing, so I hoped someone could give me some more insight, like is there any known incompatibility between those models in particular, or is one side (dimmer vs bulbs) generally more likely to be at fault than the other, or is trial and error the only way, or is very slight flickering just to be expected (maybe at this kind of price point)

Comment: From looking online there are some adjustable screws behind the switch knob. I suspect that you just need to adjust these to account for the low current of LED's. (see pics 6 and 7 at https://www.amazon.co.uk/greenandco%C2%AE-gc-350-Flush-Mounted-Dimmer-Function/dp/B08D9S58Y1). I get similar flickering on my dimmer at low levels and ive concluded its a combination of the low power draw and how bad the quality of power is).

Comment: I have given up on dimmers and led lights. And started removing the dimmers 2 years ago. I  have done 12, 4 more to go. The only dimmers that work fine for me are strip lights.